# How does the Orville's quantum drive work?

Tags: the-orville

The quantum drive used by Union ships behave like Federation (Star Trek) warp drives for all intents and purposes. It uses three engines to enter a warped space bubble that allows it to travel faster than light when measured in normal space.

In Federation starships, this is achieved by generating a warp field by driving warp plasma through warp coils. How does the Union quantum drive work? What quantum effects are at play?

Comment: Very well, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few (vague) descriptions of how the drive works. Nothing concrete, unfortunately

---

**It has something to do with space being *quantized***

> **André:** *... We have a faster-than-light drive system, which we call quantum drive as opposed to warp drive (the idea being that
> space, at the deepest level, is quantized, like the energy levels in
> atoms, and if someday we understand how this works we might be able to
> manipulate the fabric of space to travel faster than light).*
>
> *Our power source is called Dysonium, a fictional transuranic element we named in honor of the physicist Freeman Dyson.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Aliens and AI: André Bormanis Explores the Science Behind 'The Orville](https://www.outerplaces.com/science/item/16774-orville-interview-andre-bormanis)</sup></sub>

**The shape of the rings is important, they're tori, not just semi-circles**

> *Bormanis has written a whole show bible about the various science
> elements within the universe of The Orville. A good amount is
> dedicated to the ship. On The Orville you don’t have a warp drive, but
> you do have a “quantum drive.” And for this faster than light sci-fi
> ship they are using the theories of physicist Miguel Alcubierre who
> has postulated a form of drive that works within Einstein’s general
> relativity. And this theory’s call for torus rings are what is behind
> the rings of the U.S.S. Orville itself. They have even named the
> exotic matter that is required for such a drive “Dysonium” after
> physicist Freeman Dyson.*
>
> <sub><sup>[6 Takeaways From A Set Visit To ‘The Orville’](https://trekmovie.com/2017/08/31/6-takeaways-from-a-set-visit-to-the-orville/)</sup></sub>

Each of the rings represents an engine. Each engine contains *something* that requires containment. Presumably that something (dysonium?) is traveling around the rings at high speed.

> **Newton:** *Sir, we've lost both quantum phase inducers in the upper engine! I need to divert all available power to the **containment regulators** now!*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Orville #10](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-orville-2017&episode=s01e10)</sup></sub>